# Where's the checkbox to disable or remove all versions of Internet Explorer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

On my Windows 7 Professional install I want to completely remove Internet Explorer and go with Google Chrome.

After a fresh install of Windows, I wanted to get rid of the Internet Explorer 9. So I had to *remove the update* again. But that left me with Internet Explorer 8, which I can't remove like other programs as  there is *no entry in the list of currently installed programs*.

The last time I installed Windows 7 I somehow managed to disable the Internet Explorer via a check-box setting. I wish I could be more specific, but I really don't know where the check-box was. It was very simple and worked just like that.

#### Do you know where this setting to disable the Internet Explorer is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start, control panel, uninstall programs, turn windows features on or off. I'm on my cell right now, so I well expand a bit later on a computer

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to come back and mark as the answer too for some extra reputation on your part